# c# cannot set visibility of parent control to 'Visible' and child control to 'Collapsed'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**EDIT**

I am restructuring the question to make it more clear.

The application I am working on has loging screen (Called `MainWindow`) and the main application (called `HomeWindow`).

Once a user enters his/her crendentials, a click event is fired (I reduced the code for simplicity)

```
private void BtnHello_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   HomeWindow homeWindow = new HomeWindow();
   MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
   HRLevel1UserControl hRLevel1UserControl = new HRLevel1UserControl();
   StudentsLevel1UserControl studentsLevel1UserControl = new StudentsLevel1UserControl();

    homeWindow.ItemHR.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    homeWindow.ItemStudents.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    homeWindow.ItemClass.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    homeWindow.ItemFinances.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    homeWindow.ItemSchool.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    homeWindow.ItemReports.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    foreach (UserCategory userCategory in new CheckConnection().CheckPrivilege(LoggedInData.LoggedInUserId, LoggedInData.LoggedInstitutionId))
    {
      if (userCategory.Role == TeacherRole)
      {                                                
       homeWindow.ItemStudents.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                                                
       studentsLevel1UserControl.StudentManageBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                                                
       studentsLevel1UserControl.StudentReportBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;                                                
       homeWindow.MenuBarSettings.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
       }
       else
       {
          MessageBox.Show("-", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Stop);
          return;
       }
    }
   this.Close();
   homeWindow.Show();
}
```

The `homeWindow` is the main application window and it is created based on the followinf XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Frame BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2"/>
            <Grid Name="MainGrid" Background="White" Margin="140 5 5 5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Grid Margin="4 4 0 5" Width="132" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,2.5" StartPoint="1,0" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" SpreadMethod="Pad" Opacity="0.3">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{DynamicResource Logo}" ToolTip="Sire Systems" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ListView x:Name="ListViewMain" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ListViewMain_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListView.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </ListView.BorderBrush>
                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Width="128" x:Name="ItemAccueil" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Accueil">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource Dashboard}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Accueil" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Width="128" x:Name="ItemHR" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Ressources Humaines">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource HR}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="RH" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Width="128" x:Name="ItemStudents" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Gestion Etudiants">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource Students}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Etudiants" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Width="128" x:Name="ItemClass" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Gestion Classes">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource Classes}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Classes" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Width="128" x:Name="ItemFinances" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Gestion Finances">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource Finances}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Finances" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Width="128" x:Name="ItemSchool" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Gestion au Quotidien">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource School}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Ecole" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" Width="128" x:Name="ItemReports" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ToolTip="Rapports Globaux">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="5" Source="{DynamicResource Reports}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Rapports" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" Foreground="#FF606060"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>                        
        </Grid>        
    </Grid>
```

Each `ListViewItem` loads a usercontrol in the `MainGrid` based on the following code:

```
private void ListViewMain_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl usc = null;
            //MainGrid.Children.Clear();

            try
            {
                switch (((ListViewItem)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Name)
                {
                    case "ItemAccueil":
                        usc = new HomeUserControl();
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                    case "ItemHR":
                        usc = new UserControls.Home.HRLevel1UserControl() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                    case "ItemStudents":
                        usc = new UserControls.Students.StudentsLevel1UserControl() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                    case "ItemClass":
                        usc = new UserControls.Classes.ClassLevel1UserControl() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                    case "ItemFinances":
                        usc = new UserControls.Finances.FinancesLevel1UserControl() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                    case "ItemSchool":
                        usc = new UserControls.School.SchoolLevel1UserControl() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                    case "ItemReports":
                        usc = new UserControls.Reports.ReportsLevel1UserControl() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                    default:
                        usc = new HomeUserControl();
                        MainGrid.Children.Add(usc);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
```

One of the UserControls that is loaded is the students usc, called `StudentsLevel1UserControl` (see part of the code: `case "ItemStudents"`). And here is the XAML for that usercontrol:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource UpperGridStyle}">
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource UscMenuBarStyle}">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF005C8B"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FF3284CB"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="12.5"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <RadioButton Uid="0" x:Name="StudentManageBtn" Width="120" Content="Gestion Etudiants" Height="Auto" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <RadioButton Uid="1" x:Name="StudentRatingsBtn" Width="130" Content="Evaluations" Height="Auto" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <RadioButton Uid="2" x:Name="StudentPassingBtn" Width="120" Content="Passage de Classe" Height="Auto" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <RadioButton Uid="3" x:Name="StudentReportBtn" Width="120" Content="Rapports Etudiants" Height="Auto" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>            
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="StudentsMain" Margin="5 55 5 5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
```

As you can see, this usercontrol contains four `RadioButtons` and what I am trying to achieve is set the `Visibility` of `StudentManageBtn` and `StudentReportBtn` to `COllapsed` based on whether the user logging in is a teacher or not. So far, the method that I have used (in the `BtnHello_Click` button) is not working.

For completeness, here is the code-behind for the usercontrol

```
public partial class StudentsLevel1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        public StudentsLevel1UserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserControl usctrl = new StudentsManageStudentsUsc();
            StudentsMain.Children.Add(usctrl);
            StudentManageBtn.IsChecked = true;
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = int.Parse(((RadioButton)e.Source).Uid);
            StudentsMain.Children.Clear();
            UserControl usctrl = null;
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0:
                    usctrl = new StudentsManageStudentsUsc() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                    StudentsMain.Children.Add(usctrl);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    usctrl = new StudentsEvaluateStudentsUsc() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                    StudentsMain.Children.Add(usctrl);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    usctrl = new StudentsClassPassingUsc() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                    StudentsMain.Children.Add(usctrl);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    usctrl = new StudentsReportsUsc() { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
                    StudentsMain.Children.Add(usctrl);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where're you doing it? In constructor or event handler?

Comment: In event handler: Click event

Comment: Ok, event handler of what? Please give more code making me able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `Button.Click` event handler in parent window. It works. *This is the button that loads the usercontrol* please explain, what do you mean? How does it loads the Control?

Comment: Still can't catch the idea how the `UserControl` is attched to the `Window`. Where it is embedded or created in `homeWindow` or `MainWindow`? How?

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation in the question. The code is quite a lot so I have tried to summarize as best as I can. The logic is: On click event, I set the visibility of the controls, then load the HomeWindow. The HomeWIndow contains many usercontrols, including the usercontrol studentsLevel1UserControl

Comment: Then you shoud address the `UserControl` as something like `homeWindow.studentsLevel1UserControl...`. Now you're trying to change it in `MainWindow`.

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work. The usercontrol is not recognized when I add ``homeWindow.studentsLevel1UserControl``

Comment: Here's the objective: find a way to access nested controls in `UserControl`. Now you're accessing the wrong `homeWindow` that appears to be in current window, not `homeWindow`. I can't help here now because i don't know how did you created the `homeWindow` and usercontrols inside it. Wait. What type of variable `homeWindow` is? And what's name of its class?

Comment: Subscribe to the homeWindow.Loaded and studentsLevel1UserControl.Loaded event. Then in the event handler toggle the visibility of the controls contained in HomeWindow and StudentsLevel1UserControl

Comment: You are currently doing nothing with studentsLevel1UserControl in the click handler. It will never display.

Comment: @BrunoBukavuThai: You should post the XAML markup for the `HomeWindow`.

Comment: @BionicCode How do I suscribe to the loaded event? I have been trying but can't make it happen...

Comment: @mm8: The markup for HomeWindow is added in the edit

Comment: @aepot I have added the markups and the code for loading the usercontrols...

Comment: You ignored my last comment. Ccorrect me if I am wrong: the first XAML you've posted is the `StudentsLevel1UserControl`. You titled this snippet _"The usercontrol that is loaded into the HomeWindow is:"_. The second XAML code is the `HomeWindow`, but I can't find the `StudentsLevel1UserControl`. Please show how you lod this control. Right now it looks like you are modifying the visibility of a control that is not the one you are displaying. Also pleawse confirm that this line from your `BtnHello_Click` click handler works: `homeWindow.ItemStudents.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; `.

Comment: @BionicCode I admit that the way I put my code might have made it confusing because I tried to make it simple. I have restructured my question and hopefully, now it is more clear. Thank You for you help

Comment: This is slightly better. Where is the loggedin user role stored? Is it accessible from the `StudentsLevel1UserControl`? If so, I recommend using a `DataTrigger` to toggle visibility. And still  `BtnHello_Click` does not make sense: why are you creating `MainWindow` there (you never show it)? Why are you creating `StudentsLevel1UserControl` there (you never show it or add it to a Window)? It seems this code should be removed. At least the creation and modification of `StudentsLevel1UserControl` has no effect on the actual controls displayed by the `ListViewMain_SelectionChanged` method.

Comment: And where is `MainGrid`? Also you should avoid creating controls and layout them in C#. You should use XAML and `DataTemplates`.

Comment: The loggedIn user role is stored in a class classed ``UserCategory`` that is defined in the ``MainWindow.cs`` file. The ``MainGrid`` is defined in the ``homeWindow.xaml``: 8th line from the top. The ``homeWindow`` is loaded from the ``BtnHello_Click`` at the botton of the code.

Comment: The loggedin user role is not stored is not accessible from the ``StudentsLevel1UserControl``. That's why I am handling it from the ``BtnHello_Click ``. I am not familiar with DataTrigger...How can I apply it in the context of what I am trying to achieve...? Do you have a sample from where I can iterate?

Comment: Can you make `UserCategory` a public property of `MainWindow`? How is the property path to the logged-in user role?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a `DataTrigger` inside the relevant `Style`.

To make it work, make sure the `UserCategory` is a public property of `MainWindow`.

The following example defines two styles for `RadioButton`: the existing style `MenuButtonStyle`, which applies to every `RadioButton` that has no `Visibility` constraints.
And based on the existing `MenuButtonStyle` the new `MenuButtonTeacherVisibiltyStyle`. When applied to the relevant buttons, it will collapse them if the user role is a `TeacherRole`:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void BtnHello_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  HomeWindow homeWindow = new HomeWindow() {Role = this.UserCategory.Role};

  this.Close();
  homeWindow.Show();
}
```

**StudentsLevel1UserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF005C8B"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
          <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
          <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FF3284CB"/>
          <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="12.5"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MenuButtonTeacherVisibiltyStyle" 
           TargetType="RadioButton" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=HomeWindow}, Path=Role}" Value="TeacherRole">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="StudentManageBtn" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTeacherVisibiltyStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="StudentRatingsBtn" tyle="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="StudentPassingBtn" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="StudentReportBtn" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTeacherVisibiltyStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>            
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Remarks**
You must adjust/insert the XAML namespaces to make it compile.

Comment: Do you mean I should have a namespace called homeWindow in the ``StudentsLevel1UserControl.xaml`` like this ``xmlns:MainWindow="clr-namespace:(MyProject)"``. MainWindow is not located in a specific folder. Because right now I am getting an error with the code: MainWindow is not supported in WPF project. The type "MainWindow" was not found. I have made the class ``UserCategory`` public.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Otherwise the compiler is not able to resolve `MainWindow` and the binding won't work. You must add the namespace of `MainWindow` to your `HomeWindow` XAML file and qualify the type in the binding.

Comment: I am getting an exception due to a conflict between ``homeWindow.Owner = this;`` and ``this.Close(); homeWindow.Show();``. Plus, I am still getting a compiler error that ``MainWindow is not supported in a WPF project`` and ``The type MainWindow was not found...`` even after adding ``xmlns:MainWindow="clr-namespace:(MyProject)"`` in  ``HomeWindow`` :s

Comment: I see, you are closing the `MainWIndow`. You have to preserve the login information. Since you are not working with view models you must add a public `Role` property to the `HomeWindow`. I will update the example code.

Comment: Regarding your type not supported exception you have to define the namespace. If the `MainWindow` is defined in a different assembly than `HomeWindow` you must also specify the assembly name when declaring the namespace: `xlmns:alias="clr-namespace:NameSpace;assembly=assemblyName"`.

Comment: Then use the namespace alias (in your posted code it's _MainWindow_)  and qualify the type e.g. `MainWindow:MainWindow`. By convention the namespace alias should be lowercase: `xmlns:mainWindow="clr-namespace:(MyProject)` and then use it like `mainWindow:MainWindow`. I guess (MyProject)  is your placeholder to the real namespace?

Comment: Thank You. I will apply the changes and see if it works and let you know

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to modify the example. I just did it. So please take a look again. In the example I assume that `HomeWindow` has now a property `Role` which I currently set before showing the window.